# RuntimeError: "exp" not implemented for 'torch.LongTensor'

Tags: pytorch, tensor, attention-model

I am following this tutorial: http://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html
to implement the Transformer model from the "Attention Is All You Need" paper.

However I am getting the following error : 
RuntimeError: "exp" not implemented for 'torch.LongTensor'

This is the line, in the PositionalEnconding class, that is causing the error:

```
div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2) * -(math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
```

When it is being constructed here:

```
pe = PositionalEncoding(20, 0)
```

Any ideas?? I've already tried converting this to perhaps a Tensor Float type, but this has not worked.

I've even downloaded the whole notebook with accompanying files and the error seems to persist in the original tutorial.

Any ideas what may be causing this error?

Thanks!

Comment: What is d_model in the code?

Comment: @AkhileshPandey d_model is one of the parameters to initialise the PositionalEncoding class: def __init__(self, d_model, dropout, max_len=5000):
Also the entire notebook can be found here: https://github.com/harvardnlp/annotated-transformer/blob/master/The%20Annotated%20Transformer.ipynb

Comment: After going through the code I found that at one point the value of d_model was 20. Using this value I find that the line works fine for me

Comment: Try converting it to some other type like a= a.type(torch.float36) then call torch.exp(a)

Comment: I ran the code and it works fine for me. Just see if you have copied correctly.

Comment: @noob Hey man, I'm trying to run this tutorial and I had this same problem. After applying the fix, I had a bunch of other similar problems, which I fixed by calling `float()` on some of the tensors and converting them to `FloatTensor`s. But now I'm getting this error: `Floating point exception: 8` and python quits. I was wondering if you had the same problem. If you didn't what did you do to fix those other problems with the float type?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I happened to follow this tutorial too.

For me I just got the `torch.arange` to generate float type tensor

from

```
position = torch.arange(0, max_len).unsqueeze(1)
div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2) * -(math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
```

to

```
position = torch.arange(0., max_len).unsqueeze(1)
div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0., d_model, 2) * -(math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
```

Just a simple fix. But now it works for me. It is possible that the torch `exp` and `sin` previously support `LongTensor` but not anymore (not very sure about it).

Comment: Thank you very much and welcome to Stack overflow ! :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `torch.arange` returns a `LongTensor`, try `torch.arange(0.0, d_model, 2)` to force torch to return a `FloatTensor` instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response ! But that doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: @noob are you sure this line produces this error? can you verify (in debug) that the `dtype` of `torch.arage(0, d_model, 2)` is indeed `float` and not `long`?

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion given by @shai worked for me.  I modified the `init` method of `PositionalEncoding` by using `0.0` in two spots:

```
position = torch.arange(0.0, max_len).unsqueeze(1)
div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0.0, d_model, 2) * -(math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
```

Comment: For me also (same tutorial; code copied to *.py script): needed to swap `0,` to `0.0,` as indicated above.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me, installing `pytorch == 1.7.1` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like Rubens said, in the higher version of Pytorch, you don't need to worry about this stuff. I can easily run it on my desktop's 1.8.0 Pytorch, but failed to go through it in my server's 1.2.0 Pytorch. There is something incompatible between different versions.